# Returning count result on multiple columns based on different dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table that has lots of data. I want to extract distinct result count based on data that came in within 48hours and within 30 days (for comparision)

```
Fog||Count48hr(fog)||Count30day(fog)||Snow||Count48hr(snow)||Count30day(snow)
LA01    1123            3000           NWC        54               109
SIU     3665            7000           SIS        21                64
CHARTN  444             1500           PHS        39                120
```

Note: each of those counts are the number of occurrences of each either within 48hours or 30 days

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you provide sample tables. We don't know how your input data is structured. Also, it is unclear to me what the _Fog_ and _Snow_ columns represent - they look like locations, but how/why is `LA01` paired with `NWC` and `SIU` paired with `SIS` and `CHARIN` paired with `PHS`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The table has many columns but the columns i'm interested in is the Fog, Snow and arrival_time. LA01, SIU and CHARTN is a type of fog while NWC, SIS and PHS is another type of snow. The arrival_time is the recorded time. So i need to count the number of occurences of LA01 within 48hours and also the last 30days. Same thing for others. Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: @DiD Is the table you posted the data you already have, or a representation of what you are hoping to get as output?  I ask because I don't see an `arrival_time` column in the table you posted.  Can we assume that it is a column of type `TIMESTAMP` or something similar?

Comment: Its a representation of what i want to get Yes, it has a column for arrival_time. The columns i used from the table are fog, snow and arrival_time. I how that answers your question @rchang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to do this with two separate queries (one for fog, one for snow), you can perform a conditional sum on the data that only increments the count if `arrival_time` meets the desired criteria.

```
-- Fog
SELECT
  fog,
  SUM(CASE WHEN NOW() - arrival_time < INTERVAL '48 HOURS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    AS count48hr_fog,
  SUM(CASE WHEN NOW() - arrival_time BETWEEN INTERVAL '48 HOURS' AND
    INTERVAL '30 DAYS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count30day_fog
FROM your_table
GROUP BY fog;
```

And then you could do the same thing again, replacing the "fog" columns with the "snow" columns (and probably renaming the output columns as well).

This assumes that in your count you are looking at snow and fog independently - if for some reason you are actually counting pairings of snow and fog types (number of times LA01 occurred together with NWC within the last 48 hours, for example), then you could consolidate with this query:

```
SELECT
  fog,
  snow,
  SUM(CASE WHEN NOW() - arrival_time < INTERVAL '48 HOURS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    AS count48hr,
  SUM(CASE WHEN NOW() - arrival_time BETWEEN INTERVAL '48 HOURS' AND
    INTERVAL '30 DAYS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count30day
FROM your_table
GROUP BY fog, snow;
```

However, what you posted implies that this is not what you are looking for - I've included it just in case that use case arises for you.